# Duplicate Rows when rows is being copied and paste from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that allow me to filter based on the countries that i would like to copy and paste it from one workbook to another. However a problem that i face was when i run the code for more than once, duplicate rows is found. I am not sure how to make the improvement on the code to allow the codes to prevent a duplication of rows from happening. Below is the code that i currently have. It gave a duplication of the rows when copied from external workbook. The condition that i would like to search is "Singapore" and it appear more than once in the external workbook called "Active master project". Thus the code below will help to find all the rows contain "Singapore" and paste it into the other workbook that has a sheet called "New Upcoming Projects". However, when the codes is being run more than once, it will duplicate the rows that has already been copied previously. The external workbook will have new rows added each month thus the code below will allow to search for the "Singapore" and copy paste the rows into the another workbook. However, it also duplicate the previous rows that have been copied. Thus, I am a little stuck with the current code.

```
Sub UpdateNewUpcomingProj()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
    Dim strSearch As String

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("U:\Active Master Project.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")

    strSearch = "Singapore"
    With ws1

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
        '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Destination File
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")
     With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 2
        End If

       copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Below is the external workbook called Active Master Project which is used to refer to search for "Singapore" 
[image]

with the code above the information will be paste to the "New Upcoming Project" workbook. Look Like this:
[image] 
However when i run the code again, the information above will be duplicated.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: How many columns are in each of your rows? Is it always the same number of columns? What will we need to look at in your data to determine if a row is a duplicate (i.e. are we lucky enough to have a serial number of sorts on each row or do we need to go column by column)?

Comment: Hi there are more than 5 columns. An yes it is the same number of columns. Each Rows have a project ID but the code works for searching through the column that have "Singapore" in it. I have made some adjustment to my question with some images. maybe you can take a look to understand my question better @Brumder22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be duplicated anytime you re-run the code because you are not checking for duplication in the destination sheet. One way to fix this is through checking for the duplicates before copying, for example on the projectId field...

But a simple and fast fix would be to remove the duplicated rows after the copy operation, like this:

right after `copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)`

```
.Rows.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2, 3, 4), xlNo
```

This will remove duplicate rows based on all columns A, B, C and D. You probably would want to check based on the projectId, so the array would only be Array(2), or on more columns, just put their indexes in the Array. Sure it is not an esthetic solution, but avoids you to check for duplicates row by row from the source and the destination (two nested loops).

Comment: Hi i have to search through "Singapore" because in the "New Upcoming Projects" the sheet is empty. So the information will be copied and paste when "Singapore" is found in the external workbook. That is why i could not use the Project ID

Comment: @nabilah yes, but when you run the code a second time, you are not checking if the destination already has the rows, are you?

Comment: I wanted to have it check but not sure of the codes to use. I tried adding in the codes you gave but it kind of give the same result as in still duplicate it

Comment: ahh, maybe there are formulas in there?

Comment: what do you mean by there are formulas?

Comment: I mean if some of the fields are formulas that refer to other fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90944/discussion-between-a-s-h-and-nabilah).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to check if your search string already exists, then you could just use another `Find` test and, if nothing is found, paste the results, like so...

```
Dim duplicateRng As Range

' // ... //

Set duplicateRng = .Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=True)

If duplicateRng Is Nothing Then
    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End If
```

But if you want to check each cell in each row for a match with each cell in your paste rows then you'd really need to run a loop and test all the values.

Comment: Hi but the codes you given will it allow and adding into new rows of information too. Because in the external workbook, There is more than 1 "SIngapore" being found in a column. I would need all the rows which have "Singapore" found to be copied to the another workbook. That is why  i used the previous code to add in the rows from external workbook but when i run it again the code, it become duplicated